# Setting values of data-id dynamically in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I'm new to node js express js and jquery and trying to practice it. I was building an CRUD application while i had this problem.
Whenever I try to access the data-id value it always shows it as '1'(as i stored the first id of student as '1' in the database) which is really confusing. Please tell me what is the issue. **(P.s I know that i can do it without using ajax requests and can use 'a' tag but i want to practice jquery)** It has been 3 hours but still can't find the problem

```
  <tbody>
    <% for(var iterator = 0 ; iterator < obj.length ; iterator++){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= obj[iterator].id %></td>
            <td><%= obj[iterator].fullName %></td>
            <td><button data-id="<%= obj[iterator].id %>" id="update">Update</button></td>
            <td><button data-id="<%= obj[iterator].id %>" id="delete">Delete</button></td>
        </tr><br>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
<script src="/submit.js"></script>
```

Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('form').submit(()=>{

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/students',
            data: {
                id: $('#id').val(),
                fullName: $('#fullName').val()
            },
            success: (data)=>{
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });

    $("#clear").click(()=>{
        $('#id').val("");
        $('#fullName').val("");
    });

    $('button').click(()=>{
        alert($('#update').attr('data-id'));
    });
});
```